# How to merge data from 2 ngrx effects

Tags: angular, merge, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have 2 effects where in both are called at different user actions. They have the same return type. I want to merge data from 1 effect into another effects data. (and later remove the duplicate records in them)

```
    loadQueues$ =  this.actions$.ofType(qeueActions.LOAD_QUEUE_DETAILS).pipe(
map((action: qeueActions.LoadQueues) => action.payload),
switchMap( (criteria) => {
  return this.api.listMessagesByCriteria(criteria).pipe(
    map( data => new qeueActions.LoadQueuesSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => of(new qeueActions.LoadQueuesFail(error)))
  );
})// switchMap
); // pipe
```

The 2nd effect is

```
   @Effect()
 loadQueuesByDuration$ =  
 this.actions$.ofType(qeueActions.LOAD_QUEUE_DETAILS_BY_DURATION).pipe(
 map((action: qeueActions.LoadQueuesbyDuration) => action.payload),
  switchMap( (duration) => {
   return this.api.listMessageHeadersByDuration(duration).pipe(
    map( data => new qeueActions.LoadQueuesSuccess(data)),
    catchError(error => of(new qeueActions.LoadQueuesFail(error)))
  );
})// switchMap
); // pipe
```

Both success calls are the same.( So it is like merging the current data into the previous data) How do we achieve merge of the above 2 effects data?

Comment: Do the merging and removal of the duplicated in the reducer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@Effect()` decorators from `loadQueuesByDuration$` and `loadQueuesByDuration$`.

Then create a third variable with the `@Effect()` decorator:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

...

@Effect()
loadQueuesMerged$ = merge(this.loadQueues$, this.loadQueuesByDuration$).pipe(
    // logic to remove duplicates
    );
```